# What is the syntax to declare a unique_Ptr variable in a header, then assign it later in the constructor?

Tags: c++-cli, unique-ptr

I have coded the following, and am very new to c++, and it feels clumsy. I am trying to give 'spriteBatch' (a unique_Ptr) class scope. Here's the header file:

```
    ref class CubeRenderer : public Direct3DBase
{
public:
    CubeRenderer();
    ~CubeRenderer();


private:

    std::unique_ptr<SpriteBatch> spriteBatch;

};
```

Then in the cpp file Constructor, this:

```
std::unique_ptr<SpriteBatch> sb(new SpriteBatch(m_d3dContext.Get()));
spriteBatch = std::move(sb);
```

It just seems clumsy the way I had to create 'sb' and move it to 'spriteBatch'. attempting to assign directly to 'spriteBatch' failed (maybe I simply don't know the proper syntax). Is there a way to avoid needing to use 'sb' & std::move?

Thank you.

Comment: If this is in the constructor, you can just use a member initializer.

Comment: Ah, thanks, but actually my code above does not compile so my question was a bit premature. Back to square 1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following should work fine:

```
spriteBatch = std::unique_ptr<SpriteBatch>(new SpriteBatch(m_d3dContext.Get()));
```

Alternatively, you can avoid repeating the type name with some [`make_unique` function](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/).

```
spriteBatch = make_unique<SpriteBatch>(m_d3dContext.Get());
```

There's also the [`reset` member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset):

```
spriteBatch.reset(new SpriteBatch(m_d3dContext.Get()));
```

But, since you mention a constructor, why not just use the member initialization list?

```
CubeRenderer::CubeRenderer()
: spriteBatch(new SpriteBatch(m_d3dContext.Get())) {}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I must have be doing something incorrectly (probably in the header). Most of the methods you list produce the following compiler complaints: cuberenderer.h(48): error C2065: 'SpriteBatch' : undeclared identifier
cuberenderer.h(48): error C2065: 'SpriteBatch' : undeclared identifier
cuberenderer.cpp(14): error C2663: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx>::unique_ptr' : 7 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer

Comment: I was lacking a 'using' directive. That was giving me all the compile errors. Once I got past that, all your methods worked. Thank you!!

Comment: Does make_unique or the initializer list have any differences? I'm interested in performance.

Comment: Wait, so how where you able to create a non-managed member in a managed object? For me that just doesn't compile!